# Paste string with superscript in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, superscript

I am trying to pass a variable `toPaste` which is a string that I want part of it to be superscripeted. The string: `"this^2/that^+"` where `2` and `+` are desired to be superscripted.

I browsed around, and it seems, I need to reformat my string, and then I can `paste()` in a `bquote()` for example, but since the desired superscript is embedded in the middle of the string, I am not sure how to approach it. Sample script below:

```
library(ggplot2)
toPaste <- "this^2/that^+"
ggplot() + ylab(toPaste)
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Please look up `?bquote`

Comment: @Mossa My objective is to pass the variable `toPaste`, and not use `bequote` with string of interest. thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
toPaste <- "this^2/that^'+'"
ggplot() + ylab(parse(text = toPaste))
```

Note that the "+" sign needs to be surrounded by single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `latex2exp` to use LaTeX for stuff like this

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)

data("mtcars")

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = TeX("Title: $\\frac{this^{2}}{\\that^{+}}$"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `expression`:

```
ggplot() + ylab(expression(this^2/that^"+"))
```

[image]

Comment: How would you get the output here, but by passing the variable `toPaste`. So, in addition of using `bequote()` or `expression()` I can pass the variable, i.e. `ylab(toPaste)`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in `bquote`:

```r
ggplot() + ylab(bquote(this^2/that^"+"))
```

Comment: The question is more of how to pass: `ggplot() + ylab(toPaste)` with dseired formatting.